AMD HIP doesn't work on AMD GPU | Kernel hip function can't set values of variables (hip kernel doesn't work)
I have a problem with calling a global kernel function. It doesn't seem to work for me.
I downloaded hip 6.1 and created AMD HIP 6.1 Runtime (Matrix Transpose sample project). I have checked everything and I can safely say that hipMalloc and hipMemcpy are not the problem, they work fine.
Current code:
#include "msvc_defines.h"
#include <hip/hip_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <vector>

#define HIP_CHECK(status)                                                                                     \
    if (status != hipSuccess) {                                                                               \
        fprintf(stderr, "error: '%s'(%d) at %s:%d\n", hipGetErrorString(status), status, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        exit(0);                                                                                              \
    }

// Device (Kernel) function, it must be void
__global__ void matrixTranspose(float* out, float* in, const int width) {
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    out[y * width + x] = in[x * width + y];
}

// CPU implementation of matrix transpose
void matrixTransposeCPU(float* output, float* input, const unsigned int width) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
            output[i * width + j] = input[j * width + i];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    hipDeviceProp_t devProp;
    HIP_CHECK(hipGetDeviceProperties(&devProp, 0));
    std::cout << "Device name " << std::string(devProp.name) << std::endl;
    const uint32_t WIDTH = 64;
    const uint32_t NUM = WIDTH * WIDTH;
    float* Matrix = (float*)malloc(NUM * sizeof(float));
    float* TransposeMatrix = (float*)malloc(NUM * sizeof(float));
    float* cpuTransposeMatrix = (float*)malloc(NUM * sizeof(float));
    // Initialize the input data
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) 
    {
        Matrix[i] = (float)(i + 1) * 10.987654f;
    }
    // MatrixTranspose computation on CPU
    matrixTransposeCPU(cpuTransposeMatrix, Matrix, WIDTH);
    float* gpuMatrix = 0;
    float* gpuTransposeMatrix = 0;
    // Allocate the memory on device side
    HIP_CHECK(hipMalloc((void**)&gpuMatrix, NUM * sizeof(float)));
    HIP_CHECK(hipMalloc((void**)&gpuTransposeMatrix, NUM * sizeof(float)));
    // Memory transfer from host to device

    HIP_CHECK(hipMemcpy(gpuMatrix, Matrix, NUM * sizeof(float), hipMemcpyHostToDevice));
    //HIP_CHECK(hipMemcpy(TransposeMatrix, gpuMatrix, NUM * sizeof(float), hipMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    const uint32_t THREADS_PER_BLOCK_X = 4;
    const uint32_t THREADS_PER_BLOCK_Y = 4;
    const uint32_t THREADS_PER_BLOCK_Z = 1;
    const uint32_t GRID_X = uint32_t(WIDTH / THREADS_PER_BLOCK_X);
    const uint32_t GRID_Y = uint32_t(WIDTH / THREADS_PER_BLOCK_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid(GRID_X, GRID_Y);
    dim3 dimBlock(THREADS_PER_BLOCK_X, THREADS_PER_BLOCK_Y, THREADS_PER_BLOCK_Z);
    
    // Lauching kernel from host
    //matrixTranspose <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, 0 >>> (gpuTransposeMatrix, gpuMatrix, WIDTH);
    hipLaunchKernelGGL(matrixTranspose, dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, 0, gpuTransposeMatrix, gpuMatrix, WIDTH);
    
    // Memory transfer from device to host
    HIP_CHECK(hipMemcpy(TransposeMatrix, gpuTransposeMatrix, NUM * sizeof(float), hipMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) 
    {
        printf("Matrix[%d]: %.6f  |  TransposeMatrix[%d]: %.6f  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[%d]: %.6f\n", i, Matrix[i], i, TransposeMatrix[i], i, cpuTransposeMatrix[i]);
    }
    int errors = 0;
    const float eps = 1.0E-6;
    printf("The margin of error = %.6f\n", eps);
    // Verify the results
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
    {
        float transpose = TransposeMatrix[i];
        float cpuTranspose = cpuTransposeMatrix[i];
        float difference = std::abs(transpose - cpuTranspose);
        if (difference > eps)
            errors++;
    }
    if (errors != 0) 
    {
        printf("FAILED: %d errors\n", errors);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("PASSED!\n");
    }
    // Free the resources on device side
    HIP_CHECK(hipFree(gpuMatrix));
    HIP_CHECK(hipFree(gpuTransposeMatrix));
    // Free the resources on host side
    free(Matrix);
    free(TransposeMatrix);
    free(cpuTransposeMatrix);
    return errors;
}

The output is as follows:
Device name AMD Radeon RX 5700
Matrix[0]: 10.987654  |  TransposeMatrix[0]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[0]: 10.987654
Matrix[1]: 21.975307  |  TransposeMatrix[1]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[1]: 714.197510
Matrix[2]: 32.962959  |  TransposeMatrix[2]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[2]: 1417.407349
...
Matrix[4093]: 44983.453125  |  TransposeMatrix[4093]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[4093]: 43599.011719
Matrix[4094]: 44994.441406  |  TransposeMatrix[4094]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[4094]: 44302.218750
Matrix[4095]: 45005.429688  |  TransposeMatrix[4095]: 0.000000  |  cpuTransposeMatrix[4095]: 45005.429688
The margin of error = 0.000001
FAILED: 4096 errors

For some reason it can't assign values to a kernel function, at least it seems that way to me (TransposeMatrix[i] should be equal to cpuTransposeMatrix[i]).
So I tried to write a different code, it looks as follows:
__global__ void kernel(int* data) {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    data[idx] = idx;
}

int main() {
    const int N = 1024;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(int);

    int* host_data, * device_data;
    host_data = new int[N];
    hipMalloc(&device_data, size);

    hipLaunchKernelGGL(kernel, dim3(N / 256), dim3(256), 0, 0, device_data);

    hipMemcpy(host_data, device_data, size, hipMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    bool success = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        if (host_data[i] != i) 
        {
            success = false;
        }
        std::cout << "value of host_data[" << i << "] = " << host_data[i] << ", expected value: " << i << "\n";
    }

    if (success) 
    {
        std::cout << "Kernel is working correctly!" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Kernel is not working correctly." << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] host_data;
    hipFree(device_data);

    return 0;
}

It's simple programm that should assing [i] value of array to i (list[i] = i;), but again output looks the same:
value of host_data[0] = 0, expected value: 0
value of host_data[1] = 0, expected value: 1
value of host_data[2] = 0, expected value: 2
value of host_data[3] = 0, expected value: 3
value of host_data[4] = 0, expected value: 4
...
value of host_data[1020] = 0, expected value: 1020
value of host_data[1021] = 0, expected value: 1021
value of host_data[1022] = 0, expected value: 1022
value of host_data[1023] = 0, expected value: 1023
Kernel is not working correctly.

What could be the problem? Am I missing something?
*Sorry for my poor english
OS: Windows 10 | GPU: Rx5700
Latest driver (if it means anything)
First of all I checked hipMemcpy, I thought it couldn't copy memory to the device, it ended up working fine.
Then I started experimenting with the kernel function, i.e. I tried to set values of array to some value, but I still get zeros.
So im assuming that problem in kernel function.
UPD: I have another computer with NVIDIA GPU and the code works! I set Platform Toolset to AMD HIP for nvcc Compiler and the code worked. Seems a bit strange for me, but i will further investigate into this.
The issue is not closed, I would like to know the potential causes of this problem.
